# Clip vector with ogr2ogr by reprojecting geometries on the fly

Tags: coordinate-system, clip, ogr2ogr

I have two vector geometries which I want to clip using ogr2ogr

1. Geopackage with buildings in EPSG:28992
2. Shapefile with a neighborhood in EPSG:4326

I managed to clip the buildings using the neighborhood by reprojecting the shapefile to EPSG:28992 and saving it as a new file. However, I was wondering whether I can reproject the clipping geometry on the fly.

Something like this:

`ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' clipped_buildings.gpkg buildings.gpkg -clipsrc project_extent_wgs.shp -a_srs EPSG:28992`

This obviously didn't work. The `clipped_buildings.gpkg` file is created, but - as one might expect - it's empty.

Comment: Have a look at the Reprojected layer example in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html. Modify the example a bit to warp the neighborhood into EPSG:28992. It is not totally on-the-fly but almost.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real on-the-fly, but you can easily do that by chaining two ogr2ogr commands :

- 1 - Transform the clipping layers
- 2 - Clip your source layer

```
ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' project_extent_local.gpkg -t_srs EPSG:28992 project_extent_wgs.shp && ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' clipped_buildings.gpkg buildings.gpkg -clipsrc project_extent_local.gpkg -a_srs EPSG:28992
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing in the end. We could even add one more command to delete the intermediate result.